# Power Apps Customized Form - Auto populate selected User's Phone numbers

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, list-form, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have a Power Apps Customized SP form, and I have a requirement to auto-populate a selected user's mobile and business phone numbers. Basically I have a Project Manager people picker field, then two text fields (Mobile Phone and Work Phone).

I have the Office 365 connector in my app, but none of the formulas I've tried seem to work.  Keep getting errors.  I tried this:

```
If(
    !IsBlank(DataCardValue2.SelectedItems), First(Office365Users.UserProfile(DataCardValue2.Selected.Email).BusinessPhones).Value
)
```

But it threw an error saying No user found with the specified ID.  I've also tried just:

```
Office365Users.UserProfile(DataCardValue2.Selected.Email).BusinessPhones).Value
```

That doesn't work either.

My people picker is Datacardvalue2 (or `Thisitem.ProjectManager`)
Then I have two text fields: Mobile Phone - Work Phone

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using single selection or multiple selection people field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using single selection person or group field in SharePoint list, try using below solution which worked for me:

1. Set `Default` property of Work Phone Data card control to:

```
If(
    IsBlankOrError(ThisItem.'Work Phone'),
    If(
        !IsBlank(DataCardValue2.SelectedItems),
        First(Office365Users.UserProfileV2(DataCardValue2.Selected.Email).businessPhones).Value
    ),
    ThisItem.'Work Phone'
)
```

[image]

1. Similarly, set `Default` property of Mobile Phone Data card control to:

```
If(
    IsBlankOrError(ThisItem.'Work Phone'),
    If(
        !IsBlank(DataCardValue2.SelectedItems),
        Office365Users.UserProfileV2(DataCardValue2.Selected.Email).mobilePhone
    ),
    ThisItem.'Work Phone'
)
```

**Output - in form**:

[image]

**Output - Data saved in list**:

[image]

---

`Office365Users.UserProfileV2()` function retrieves the profile of a specified user. Learn more about available fields to select from the function output at: [User resource type properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

Comment: You can also adjust the formulas based on form mode (new/view/edit) as per your requirements.